# How do I Update ChromeDriver for Katalon Local Agent

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio, katalon

I need to update the ChromeDriver that my Katalon Local Agent uses.
*(Katalon Local Agent is running on a Windows 10 VM.)*

I would like to configure Katalon Agent to do it automatically.

But I would settle on a way to update it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took about a month going back and forth with Katalon Support, but I finally have an answer...

**Manually (Windows):**

- When running Katalon Agent as a User, Browser Agents can be found here: `C:\Users\USER\.katalon\#.#.#\Katalon_Studio_Engine_Windows_##-#.#.#\configuration\resources\drivers\`
- When running Katalon Agent as a Service, Browser Agents can be found here: `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.katalon\#.#.#\Katalon_Studio_Engine_Windows_##-#.#.#\configuration\resources\drivers\`

**Automatically (TestOps):**

When creating a Test Run Type, the **Type** as to be "*Katalon Command*". Then you can add `--config -webui.autoUpdateDrivers=true` to the Katalon Command.

Answer (score 0):

You can update ChromeDriver by Katalon Studio GUI. From the main toolbar, select **Tools > Update WebDrivers**, then select a browser in the drop-down list.

See also

https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/handle-webdrivers.html

> From the main toolbar, select Tools > Update WebDrivers > select a browser in the drop-down list.

Comment: Thanks. That works for the GUI (Katalon Studio) but not for the Katalon Local Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can update ChromeDriver by Katalon Studio.
From main Tool bar
**Tools** -> **Update WebDrivers** -> **DropDownList**